# Stay right there after reloading

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've created an Edit button in ASP.NET (C#).  When this button is clicked, it will change to a Save button and a text field will appear for editing.

The problem is this page is pretty long. If I hit an Edit button at the end of the page, it will be reloaded and the top page will show up. Then, I have to scroll the page down to the bottom to edit something.

Is there anyway to get the page stay right there when a Edit button is clicked?

Thank you!

Comment: ASP runs on the server.  To control page behavior try clientside javascript.

Comment: You could also wrap the button/edit field in an anchor, and make your edit button direct you to the editable version of the page, at that anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```